# I can't post without error: Post contains code not formatted correctly

Tags: support

When I attempt to post the following question:

> Hey, I recently started C++ using SDL2 after a long time of C# (XNA
>   and Unity3D)
>
> I don't quite get how I create objects in my project, to explain what
>   I mean..
>
> In C# you can create a class SphereObject(as different file
>   (SphereObject.cs) which then you can (from any class) do this (example
>   in MainClass.cs)

```
    namespace MyProject
     {
         class MainClass
         {
             SphereObject sphere;
             MainClass()
             {
                sphere = new SphereObject();
             }
          }
     }
```

> Which would then call the constructor in SphereObject.cs
>
> This essentially gives me an object of type SphereObject;
>
> now maybe this is a big question.. But try to explain it as easy as
>   you can
>
> How do I do this in c++?
>
> Current I have
>
> main.cpp (which is my entrypoint) MyMain.cpp MyMain.h
>
> in the constructor of main I would like to do
>
> ```
> MyMain mainClass = new MyMain();
> ```
>
> which would then call the constructor of MyMain.cpp.
>
> I've searched google around a bit and even saw a few stackoverflow
>   refs, but they're all not what I need (they have 1 huge file with
>   different classes in it.. which is already possible but not what I
>   need (way too obscuring)

I get an error that "Post contains code not formatted correctly". What can I do about that?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy seems you have removed code block that was there originally. Could you bring it back? Sadly, I can't find a way to put code block inside a quote (hardly needed it).

Comment: @Mołot: looks fine on my computer, weird. Maybe just revert it to the original?

Comment: Now, after edit by user3012995, it does look acceptable on mine too. Actually, [your version seen as revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/208185/2) looks even better than current one. But when I was looking at it in a regular way, it wasn't :( Of course I'm perfectly OK to assume it was a glitch on my computer if you say you have seen it OK.

Comment: @Mołot: I was looking at revisions just now, so I'm not sure whether it's broken on the actual post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you might want to check your spelling/punctuation/grammar - fixing this up will make your post look significantly better.

Anyway, to the actual issue. This seems to trigger the checker:

```
main.cpp (which is my entrypoint)
MyMain.cpp
MyMain.h
```

Change that to:

```
- main.cpp (which is my entrypoint)
- MyMain.cpp
- MyMain.h
```

When testing with a 1 rep sockpuppet account, this stopped the error message. Regardless, there are numerous improvements to the formatting that can be done - this gives a much better impression of putting effort into your question.

Comment: Yes that is it, I don't see why we can't just use code brackets here

[code]
//code here
[/code] is alot easier

Comment: @Themperror you can use \`code ticks\` if you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be:

> reformat your post

Some tips:

The main issues that cause the validation logic to think your post contains code which is not formatted are the number of *short* (less than 80 characters), non-code (not starting with four spaces) lines that contain stuff like dots `.`, parentheses `()` or even end with a semicolon `;`.